# MySQL, PHP: Select * from table where id is not in array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

so I currently have a database table where I am trying to select all of the records EXCEPT for those that are included in an array that I have made. As some background context:

The structure of the database table in question is:

```
server_status:
id int(11)
server_id int(11)
time_checked datetime
status char(1)
```

My PHP script to get the data into the hash looks like this:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT server_id, time_checked,id from server_status where   time_checked<'$date' order by server_id;";
$result2=$conn->query($sql2);
while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){

 $server_id = $row2['server_id'];
 $id = $row2['id'];
 $dt = $row2['time_checked'];

 $year = substr($dt,0,4);
 $month = substr($dt,5,2);
 $day = substr($dt,8,2);

 $day = "$year-$month-$day";

 $all[$server_id][$day] = $id;  // ARRAY

}
```

So what I'm trying to do is create a MySQL query that reads in the ids ($id) from the array, and selects * APART from that. From looking it up, it seems like I will have to use a 'where not' clause, but I do not know how to reference the hash in this.

Further clarification: I now have an array which extracts data which looks like this:

```
1{
2016-05-05 : 252
2016-05-10 : 406
2016-04-27 : 141
2016-05-04 : 164
2016-05-09 : 263
2016-05-03 : 153
2016-04-26 : 131
2016-04-14 : 1
2016-04-18 : 31
2016-04-21 : 111
2016-04-20 : 61
2016-04-19 : 51
2016-04-15 : 21
2016-04-25 : 121
}
2{
2016-05-10 : 452
2016-05-05 : 198
2016-05-09 : 264
2016-05-04 : 165
2016-04-26 : 132
2016-04-27 : 143
2016-04-25 : 122
2016-04-21 : 112
2016-05-03 : 154
}
```

I want to take the IDs from this array (e.g. 154) and select everything in the table which doesn't have any of the above IDs. I hope this helps to clarify?!

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what do you call *hash* ?

Comment: `$all[$server_id][$day] = $id;` sorry I think I might be using terminology used by my boss! :P in PHP it may be known as a multi-dimensional array? But I thought it was recognised as a hash by it's square brackets.

Comment: ?? there is no hash. and with this explanation your goal became even more unclear

Comment: try to provide some example of records set where you select from. and expected result you want to get

Comment: I think you are mixing concepts, in php hash is a _message digest_, so what's a hash for you? xD

Comment: thank you for clarifying haha I have now changed my question a little!

Comment: It is still confusing... If you mean something like java's `HashMap`, use the terms _array_, _key_ and _value_ instead. So, help us understand, you have the `$all` array ready to use (mapped by `server_id` and `date` _keys_) and want a query where the column `id` is not equal to any of the _values_ in `$all`? Is it that you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOLVE:

```
$sql2 = "SELECT server_id, time_checked,id from server_status where time_checked<'$date' order by server_id;";
$result2=$conn->query($sql2);
while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){


 while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){
    $server_id = $row2['server_id'];
    $id = $row2['id'];
    $dt = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row2['time_checked']));
    $all[$server_id][$dt] = $id;  // ARRAY
 }
}

 $stack = array();
  $keys = array_keys($all);
  for($i = 0; $i < count($all); $i++) {
      foreach($all[$keys[$i]] as $key => $value) {
        array_push($stack, $value);
      }
  }


$ids = join(',',$stack);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM server_status WHERE time_checked<'$date' AND id NOT IN ($ids)";
$result=$conn->query($sql);
echo "Server status data has been deleted.<br>";
```

Created another array from the multi-dimensional array to store the ids only and use NOT IN like John Green suggested.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In case `$all` is the array you want to extract the unwanted ids from, this might be what you need after the code you provided:

```
$ids_to_exclude = array();

// iterate through servers
foreach ($all as $server_id => $dates) {
    // iterate through dates of each server
    foreach ($dates as $date => $id) {
        // If a value is not in the array, add it.
        // In case ids don't repeat, you won't need this if
        if (!in_array($id, $ids_to_exclude)) {
             // add $id to the array
             $ids_to_exclude[] = $id;
        }
    }
}

$sql_condition = "where `id` not in (".implode(",",$ids_to_exclude).")";
```

Just be careful when writing queries with string concatenation. Read about [SQL Injection](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp) and how to prevent it. Use [Prepared Statements](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp) instead of pure concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want a NOT IN, right?

```
$sql2 = "SELECT id, server_id, time_checked,id 
         FROM server_status 
         WHERE 
            id NOT IN (".implode(',', $id_array)."
            AND time_checked<'$date' 
         ORDER BY server_id;";

$result2=$conn->query($sql2);

while($row2 = $result2->fetch_assoc()){   
   $server_id = $row2['server_id'];
   $id = $row2['id'];
   $dt = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($row2['time_checked']));
   $all[$server_id][$dt] = $id;  // ARRAY 

}
```

Comment: How would I define $id_array please? :)

Comment: a PHP array of IDs.  If your IDs are numeric, something like `$id_array = array(1,5,12,24,33);`